# What weight of dead blow hammer is best of pounding together a large number of plastic crate kits

Tags: tools, hand-tools

I need to assemble a large number of aquablox plastic water matrixes (they are essentially milk crates that snap together) and the instruction video says that a dead weight hammer is best.

What weight should I get?  2lb or 3lb?

Comment: I would guess it is not the weight of the hammer so much as which one feels better holding it while swinging the hammer.  Plastic will not like heavy blows anyway.

Comment: get both ... your question is really opinion based ... such is off topic here

Comment: you can wrap a sock on a regular hammer/mallet to achieve a similar functionality, at least for this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [user's manual](https://www.aquascapeinc.com/download/138/instruction-manuals/7891/aquablox-snorkel-and-centipede-instructions-29491-29492-29065-29064-29068-29238-29066) doesn't mention using any tools at all to assemble the AquaBlox modules. Which makes me think *it just doesn't matter*. I think you can use *any* type of hammer that (a) is comfortable for you to use (which generally means not too heavy) and (b) is not going to damage the plastic (so something more like a mallet than a typical framing hammer).

If you don't have something suitable, ask a friend or neighbor and see if you can borrow something. If it works well, use it. If it doesn't work so well, you'll have a better idea of what to buy.

Comment: It was in one of the youtube videos where the guy says using a dead weight hammer is a must over a rubber mallet.  I'll try the 2lb and see how that goes!